# Using a sum to return a number of records

Tags: oracle, sum

I am trying to return a number of records based on a page count that is added up as the records are selected.  The page counts vary, but I would like each batch returned to have a page count that falls in a range.  Something like this ..

```
DATA

PRINT ID      PAGE_COUNT   STATUS
1000          50           READY
1001          50           READY
1002          50           READY
1003          75           READY

select PRINT_ID, PAGE_COUNT,STATUS from PRINT_JOB
where STATUS = 'READY' and
sum (page_count)>100 and sum(page_count)<200

RETURNED

PRINT_ID      PAGE COUNT   STATUS
1000          50           READY
1001          50           READY
1002          50           READY
```

I have tried HAVING and using a sub query.  All it seems to do is bring back individual pieces that have page counts that fall in the range, not sum the total number of pages.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to group the records in order of PRINT_ID so that each group has SUM(PAGE_COUNT) > 100? I.e. 1st group in your cae is PRINT_ID 1000-1002, 2nd group 1003. The second constraint (<200) is problematic, consider what to do if you get PRONT_ID with  300 pages...

Answer (score 0):

If the question can be reformulated in grouping records in order of `PRINT_ID`, so that each group has SUM(PAGE_COUNT) > 100 (or the rest of the records at the end of the table); here one solution using [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)

In the first step I add sequential `ID` to your table ordered same as PRINT_ID, that will be used in the recursion.

```
create table  TAB_DATA as
select print_id, page_count,
row_number() over (order by print_id) as id
from data;

select * from tab_data order by id;

  PRINT_ID PAGE_COUNT         ID
---------- ---------- ----------
      1000         50          1 
      1001         50          2 
      1002         50          3 
      1003         75          4
```

The initial subquery sets the accumalator `acc` to zero and initialze the first group. The recursive subquery performs the logic of checking the limit and increasing the group id.

```
with dt(id, print_id, page_count, acc, grp) as (
 select id, print_id, page_count, 0 acc, 1 grp from tab_data where id = 1
union all
 select tab_data.id, tab_data.print_id, tab_data.page_count,
  -- accumulate
  case when 
   dt.acc+dt.page_count >  100 then /* new group, reset acc */ 0 
  else dt.acc+dt.page_count end as acc,
  -- define group
  case when 
   dt.acc+dt.page_count >  100 then /* increase group */ grp+1 
  else grp end as grp
 from tab_data, dt
 where tab_data.id=dt.id+1)
select * from dt
;
```

returns as requested

```
        ID   PRINT_ID PAGE_COUNT        ACC        GRP
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1000         50          0          1 
         2       1001         50         50          1 
         3       1002         50        100          1 
         4       1003         75          0          2
```

I'm not considering the second limit <200. But I hope this provides you the idea how to refine the rules to implement it.